# Given an index of a string how to recover the corresponding word/token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list-comprehension

Assuming we start counting from 1, I am returning in an index a position of a string, for instance:

Given:

```
s = 'hi how are you'
```

and an index `i = 4` I would like to return the full token, in this case it would be `how` or with `i=7` I would like to return `are` or with `i = 11` I would like to return `you`, if `i = 3`, then return the space . Any idea of how to get the full token given a position in a string?

Comment: Really, how `4` is connected with `how`? I see `7 = are` because `7` is zero-based index of `a`., but other indices?

Comment: I am assuming that we are starting to count from 1 to n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function, check if `s[i]` is whitespace then return whitespace. Else split the string from start to `i` and `i` to end by whitespace and concat and return the last and first elements of both split. Like this:

```
def getToken(str, i):
    if str[i] == ' ':  # if whitespace, return white space
        return str[i]
    return str[:i].split(' ')[-1]+str[i:].split(' ')[0] # else return the word
```

result:

```
>>> getToken(s, 0)
'hi'
>>> getToken(s, 1)
'hi'
>>> getToken(s, 2)
' '
>>> getToken(s, 3)
'how'
>>> getToken(s, 11)
'you'
>>> getToken(s, 10)
' '
```

Index starts from 0, if you want index starting from 1 just pass `yourindex-1` to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how `4` corresponds to `how`. But I guess `index` is the zero-based index of first letter in a string. Then you algorithm is rather simple:

```
s = 'hi how are you'

index = 0
print(s[index:].split()[0])  # prints 'hi'

index = 3
print(s[index:].split()[0])  # prints 'how'

index = 7
print(s[index:].split()[0])  # prints 'are'
```

Comment: For example with i = 4 it fails because instead of returning `how` it returns `ow`

Comment: Of course, because `4` is position of `o`. Maybe I am missing the logic of OP, but I've made consumption about it

Answer (score 2):

You should use a regular expression that returns the first word. You could use something like:

```
def find_token(index, string):
    return re.findall('\w+', string[index - 1:])[0]
```

This will find 1 or more [`\w` characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and return the first word. This will work no matter what the separator between words is.

Comment: it fails because when you pass i = 5 it returns `ow` instead of the full word which is `how`

Comment: I assumed the same as `grapes` as that is what you stated on the question, you should try to be clearer next time.